# gwt-google-apis gwt-map-3.8.0-pre throws JavaScriptException 'map' is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I think this is a bug in the pre-release of map 3.8.0 of the GWT bindings of google map, but before I go down that route I thought I would check with you-all. When I create a map and then try to add the newly created map panel/widget into a containing panel, I get an exception. If I create the map in a panel that wraps an existing html div it displays with no exception, but either way if it has a div in the HTML or does not, if I try to add it to any other panel it throws an exception.

The exception that it normally throws is:

```
gwt-google-apis gwt-map-3.8.0-pre throws JavaScriptException 'map' is not defined.
```

I have gotten other exceptions, but let's ignore those for now unless they become relevant.

Here is the link where I got the library:
[http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/detail?name=gwt-maps-3.8.0-pre1.zip&can=2&q=](http://gwt-maps-3.8.0-pre1.zip)

As an aside, I recompiled the original source with a java 1.5 compiler, but I did not change anything.

As back ground, I am porting an application that was written for Google maps v2 to v3. In the current production version the MapWidget object was added into a VerticalPanel (i.e. html table), which was adder into another VerticalPanel, ... ultimately being served through a portal. It will be a lot more extensive rewrite if I have to change this structure, so I would appreciate any insight you can provide.

I have tried a number of variations on the theme, with similar results. Many times the map will show up, but is greyed out and then if you interact with the map through a control it will usually sort itself out, sometimes not. It does not seem to matter if it is IE-8, or firefox.

My code looks like this:

```
    LatLng myLatLng = LatLng.create(39.571993, -104.998184);
    MapOptions myOptions = MapOptions.create();
    myOptions.setZoom(16.5);
    myOptions.setCenter(myLatLng);
    myOptions.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.SATELLITE);
    //com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element mapDiv = Document.get().getElementById("map_canvas");
    RootPanel root = RootPanel.get("MAP1_NetworkMapContainer");
    //HTMLPanel mapPanel = HTMLPanel.wrap(mapDiv);
    //mapPanel.setHeight("100%");
    //map = GoogleMap.create(mapPanel.getElement(), options);

    try {
        root.add(mapPanel);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.error("Received Exception ", e);
        String  error = e.toString();
    }
```

... As a widget AKA the way it was done in source for 3.0.2

```
public class MapWidget extends Widget {
    final private static String EXCEPTION_NOT_ATTACHED
        = "Map widget must be attached to window's document.";
    private GoogleMap map;

    public MapWidget(MapOptions options) {
      setElement(Document.get().createDivElement());
      map = GoogleMap.create(getElement(), options);
    }
```

... as an extension to a SimplePanel

```
public class MapPanel extends SimplePanel {
    final private static String EXCEPTION_NOT_ATTACHED
        = "Map Panel must be attached to window's document.";
    private GoogleMap map;

    public MapPanel(MapOptions options) {
      map = GoogleMap.create(getElement(), options);
    }
```

The result is always the same. If my GWT widget has an element id of a div in the HTML, it displays OK, but if I try to add the result of either a created div or a html div and then attach it to the root panel it throws the exception. It does not seem to matter if it is a root panel, or any other type of panel. that I add the mapPanel into.

Answer (score 1):

I've started to use this library : for what I do, it works.

Here is how I did:

```
public class MyMapWidget extends Composite {

  interface MyMapWidgetUiBinder
      extends UiBinder<Widget, MyMapWidget> {}

  private static MyMapWidgetUiBinder uiBinder = 
      GWT.create(MyMapWidgetUiBinder.class);

  @UiField FlowPanel mapContainer;   

  private GoogleMap map;  

  ...

  public MyMapWidget() {

       initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

       MapOptions opts = MapOptions.create();

       opts.setScaleControl(true);
       // add your map options
  ...
       opts.setCenter(LatLng.create(44.1, 0.2);
       opts.setZoom(8.0);

       map = GoogleMap.create(mapContainer.getElement(), opts);

  ...
  }
```

In the corresponding UiBinder XML file I have

```
<g:FlowPanel ui:field="mapContainer" width="500px" height="350px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to get this to work with the pre-release 1 bindings. I switched to the 3rd party bindings found here: [Google Maps V3](http://c.gwt-examples.com/api/google-maps-v3)

In the 2.5 years that this issue has languished, and the deadline for being forced off of v2 looming, I doubt that a solution from the GWT team is forthcoming.

I created a issue on the GWT site, you might want to check there for updates, or vote for it if this is affecting you. [Issue 504](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/issues/detail?id=504)